Electromagnetic potential from Maxwell's equations with magnetic monopoles
The original Maxwell's equations are given by
\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot\textbf{E}&=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}\\
\nabla\cdot\textbf{B}&=0\\
\nabla\times\textbf{E}&=-\frac{\partial\textbf{B}}{\partial t}\\
\nabla\times\textbf{B}&=\mu_0\textbf{J}+\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial\textbf{E}}{\partial t}
\end{align}
Since $\nabla\cdot\textbf{B}=0$, we can write $\textbf{B}=\nabla\times\textbf{A}$. Then we can write
\begin{align}
\textbf{E}=-\nabla\phi-\frac{\partial\textbf{A}}{\partial t}
\end{align}
And we call $(\phi/c,\textbf{A})$ electromagnetic potential.
Now if we assume that magnetic monopoles exist, Maxwell's equations become
\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot\textbf{E}&=\frac{\rho_e}{\epsilon_0}\\
\nabla\cdot\textbf{B}&=\mu_0\rho_m\\
\nabla\times\textbf{E}&=-\mu_0\textbf{J}_m-\frac{\partial\textbf{B}}{\partial t}\\
\nabla\times\textbf{B}&=\mu_0\textbf{J}_e+\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial\textbf{E}}{\partial t}
\end{align}
The magnetic field is not divergenceless anymore. My question is how can we construct electromagnetic potential in that case.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_string

Excellent question.
I have what I believe is a valid answer, but I won't give it here as I still may publish it someday.
Unpublished, it is not part of mainstream physics (yet).

Related questions: (1) Does existence of magnetic monopole break covariant form of Maxwell’s equations for potentials? , (2) Effect of introducing magnetic charge on use of vector potential

Dirac gives a 4-vector potential that is not entire; see Prahar's comment link to wiki, there is a gauge dependent singularity that you can move around. But personally I prefer Schwinger's treatment, where you simply get a pair of 4-vector potentials, one for the usual electric charges, and the other for the magnetic charges. Having a pair is sad in some sense, but it is mathematically obviously the most uncontroversial.

@naturallyInconsistent Follow up questions: Does it mean that we now have a pair of electromagnetic tensors? What is Lagrangian now?

Yes, there will be a pair; the Lagrangian is very much analogous to the usual one.
